# How to turn sound on/off globally in Android game

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working on Android game and I am providing options menu to "Turn On" or "Turn Off" the sounds and vibration of the game .I have 3 Activity and i want that if i OFF the Sound or Vibrate from any Activity of My Game it has to be OFF in all other Activity even if i move to one activity to another activity and if from any one activity i again turn ON the sound or vibration of the game it has to ON in all the other activity of the game .The basic problem is that I am not able to do that and i am confused in this. i am also not sure that which method i use to do that.Please Help me .
i have 3 class:
1)Helper Class(MySetting)
2)class1(main class)
3)class 2

Class 1(main code i try is)

```
if(MySetting.mp.isPlaying()==true){  
             ms.setSoundON(true);

         }  
         else {  
             ms.loadAudio(this); 
             MySetting.PlaySound();  
             ms.setSoundOFF(false);  
             ms.setSoundON(true);  
         }  
         Button ON=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Start); 
                  ON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                if(ms.isSoundON()==false){  
                    ms.loadAudio(Class1.this);  
                     MySetting.PlaySound();  
                     ms.setSoundOFF(false);  
                     ms.setSoundON(true);  
                     tv.setText("Sound is Start");  
                     }  
                 else {  

                     ms.setSoundON(true);  
                 } 

            }  

         });  
                  Button OFF=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);  
                  OFF.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                MySetting.StopSound();  
                ms.setSoundOFF(true);  
                ms.setSoundON(false);  
                tv.setText("Sound is Stop");  
            }  

         });  
                  Button change=(Button)findViewById(R.id.changeActivity);  
                  change.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                startActivity(new Intent(Class1.this,Class2.class));  

                    }  
                 });
```

**SAME FOR CLASS2**
HELPER CLASS CODE IS:

```
static boolean SoundON,SoundOFF;  
static MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();  
    public void loadAudio(Context context){  
                mp=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.fullmoon);  
}  
    public static void PlaySound(){  
            mp.start();  
            }  
    public boolean setSoundON(boolean on){  
        SoundON=on;  
        return SoundON;  
    }  
    public boolean setSoundOFF(boolean off){  
        SoundOFF=off;  
        return SoundOFF;  
    }  
    public boolean isSoundON(){  
        return SoundON;  
    }  
    public boolean isSoundOFF(){  
        return SoundOFF;  
    }  
    public static void StopSound(){  
        mp.stop();  
        mp.release();         
    }
```

**NOW THE PROBLEM I AM GETTING IS WHEN I SHIFT FROM ON ACTIVITY TO ANOTHER APP CRASH AT THAT TIME PLZ HELP ME AND I WANT TO ON AND OFF THE SOUND ON CLICK OF OPTION MENU **
Thanks and Regards
RizN81

Comment: That is the WORST code formatting I have seen, my eyes.. my eyes THEY BLEED :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh) class that could manage all the sounds in your activity. I haven't previously done in Android, but on C++, and I've seen in other examples ([here](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html) and [here](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-2,695.html)) that actually support my idea.

A Singleton is accessible from everywhere in your application and more importantly, there's only one instance per application, which will let you configure any sound globally.

What those links and me are telling is that having a single class that manages every sound in your game will help you:

1. simplify sound calls *(you can call every sound from a `HashMap` (for example) by `YourSoundManager.getInstance().play("soundName");` and stop them by `YourSoundManager.getInstance().stop("soundName");`, or simply copy-pasting the examples above to have a little more control in speed and sounds)* by [facading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) the calls and,
2. control any sound, just like you had a big mixing console, except it is done using nothing but code :)

From those examples it depends on what you want to do to mute your game. Either stopping all the sounds, or putting their volume down. **I'd go for stopping them at first**, as it's the simplest approach.

**EDIT:**

If you want to stop a sound when switching from an activity to another one, you can still use the singleton approach.

You can override the onResume() method so it plays the sound you are willing to use. Also check that this sound isn't playing by looking up at a HashMap that could contain any playing sound (or use other more familiar tactics). I'll write you some code that may not be working to you (as it depends on your final approach and how you manage sounds)

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    if(! SoundManager.getInstance().isPlaying("thisStageSound") ) //if it's already playing, do not stop it!
    {
        SoundManager.getInstance().stopAllSounds();
        SoundManager.getInstance().playSound("thisStageSound");
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but the problem is that what i want is when an activity is start it start playing the sound and if i change the sound setting to OFf and jump to another the activity the sound was to be still off till the user on it using the setting. can u plz help me in this ???

Comment: @RizN81 then please edit your question to explain this. I'll edit my answer as well to fit your renewed question

Comment: it showing me IllegalStateException when i switch to Class2 after stop ing the sound but if i did not stop the music and switch to Class2 its run fine.Any Help plz?

Comment: you should edit your post: instead of marking each line as code using ` (which is a one-code-line marker), you could use the curly brackets button when selecting all your code. Anyway, would you post your error stack please?

Comment: yes buddy i say hearty thanks  you .Thank you thank you very much

Comment: Then you could consider on accepting my answer for others to see it. Thanks